# Auto resize of N images to fit container

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I have the following design:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: "column", justifyContent: "space-around", alignItems: "center", flex: 1}}>
  <TopElement style={{position: "absolute", top:5}}/>
  <Image key={1}/>
  <Image key={2}/>
  ...
  <Image key={n}/>
  <BottomElement style={{position: "absolute", bottom:5}}/>
</View>
```

My `n` Images are too big to fit the wrapper container (e.g. my screen). Would it be possible to resize them (keeping aspect ratio) without touching `TopElement` and `BottomElement` current dimensions? I would like those to stick at the borders of the container.

I am not sure if there is a builtin function, if using Layout FlexBox props is the solution or maybe computing manually each Image's dimension depending on the screen height, or maybe adding another View to wrap them all...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as below:

```js
<View style={{flexDirection: "column", justifyContent: "space-around",
      alignItems: "center", flex: 1, paddingTop: 30, paddingBottom: 30}}>
  <TopElement style={{position: "absolute", top:5}}/>
  <Image resizeMode="contain" style={{flex: 1}} key={1}/>
  ...
  <Image resizeMode="contain" style={{flex: 1}} key={n}/>
  <BottomElement style={{position: "absolute", bottom:5}}/>
</View>
```

1. Use `paddingTop` & `paddingBottom` on parent `<View />`, with height of `<TopElement />` and `<BottomElement />`. Makes Top / Bottom won't overlap with image.
2. Set `<Image />` prop `resizeMode` to `'contain'`. Make image auto resize with keeping original aspect ratio.

Comment: Thanks it works in some way: images are scaled to fit but the more images, the smaller they are resized: 1st image is almost like the original while the last one got his sizes divided by .. maybe 10! Would it be possible to make them scale proportionally at each other?

Comment: @Arkon you need a grid component for that. *react-native-photo-grid*:  build a grid of photos with a flexible number of photos per row. https://github.com/christopherabouabdo/react-native-photo-grid

Comment: Thanks I just made it! I used your answer and added `{{flex: i}}` on each picture where `i` is the index of my Image array in the map function that iterates over them.